# How to populate a model at the end of the user registration

Tags: python, django

I have the model `AuthCustomUser(AbstractUser)` for the registration of a new user. In it will be saved the necessary data for the login, for example: *name*, *email* and *password*.

On the other hand, I have the model `MetaUser (models.Model)` that I will use for the additional information of the user, for example: *address*, *telephone*, etc.

I want to create a relationship between both models at the moment of the end of the registration by the user.

In the model `MetaUser(models.Model)` I have a foreign key:

```
user = models.ForeignKey (settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

When the user is registered the data will be entered in the model `AuthCustomUser (AbstractUser)`, then I want to insert the user's 'ID' in the model `MetaUser (models.Model)` to make the relation of the foreign key between both Models. Finally, the user will start session immediately after finishing his registration, and he will be given access to the `home.html`.

These are my models:

```
class MetaUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    screen_orientation = models.CharField(default='landscape', max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AuthCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here are my view of the registry:

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        username = self.request.POST['username']
        password = self.request.POST['password1']
        user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
        login(self.request, user)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            metaUser = MetaUser(user=self.request.user.id)
            metaUser.save()
        else:
            return render(self.request, 'home.html', {})
```

I can not have the ID inserted into the foreign key field at the time of registration.

Comment: Why are you  trying to use authenticate here? Instead of authenticating just create `AuthCustomUser` model and add it to `MetaUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can have the user id. You can do it like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
    login(self.request, user)
    metaUser = MetaUser(user=user, screen_orientation='some value')
    metaUser.save()
    return render(self.request, 'home.html', {})
```

Also, you need to make sure if the newly created user is active, else authenticate will not return the user object. To ensure User is active, you can override the `create_user` method inside ModelManager. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given username, email, and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_active=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class AuthCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also, its better to have a different view for rendering home page. For example:

```
def home(request):
    return render(self.request, 'home.html', {})

# url

path('home/', home, name="home")

# usage in SignUp view

 def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    return redirect('home')  # instead of render(self.request, 'home.html', {})
```